# Using motors to ring a bell?

Tags: building, motor

I would like to create a motor set up so I can use it to ring a bell inside a small tower. Since I haven't used any of the current LEGO motors was wondering what the group would suggest.

1. which motor to use.
2. which battery/switch to use.

What I need is a simple switch with a motor. Something that I can turn off and on with out much trouble.

Comment: I'm guessing this is not a Mindstorms question. If it were, I'd suggest the original RCX motor, a loop of string around two pulleys, making the on/off button a touch sensor.

Comment: do you want one bell ping per button press, continuous ringing while button pressed/switch on, or some other pattern? The answers vary. And what bell will you use, since Lego don't AFAIK make a metal bell. Or do you mean a piezoelectric buzzer (or similar)?

Comment: @Ӎσᶎ I'm going to assume the question asker is going to use a metal bell since he/she would like to use a motor. It would be helpful to have those other points clarified.

Answer (score 2):

LEGO Power Functions would probably be the most suitable option. You could use a [PF M-Motor (8883)](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/LEGO-Power-Functions-M-Motor-8883?fromListing=listing) combined with a [PF AAA Battery Box (88000)](http://shop.lego.com/en-GB/LEGO-Power-Functions-AAA-Battery-Box-88000?fromListing=listing) which has a two-way switch and is more than capable of powering four medium size or two extra large motors (each item sold separately).

Comment: As to the design, that's completely up to you and dependent on the construction of your bell tower. I'd be more capable of answering your question if you gave some more details.